# Magento PHP-FPM cannot set Mage_Run_Code

Tags: php, magento, environment

I recently came across a issue when I am trying to set up multi site for a client.
Everything works fine from my local, but after I deploy to the server and found out the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` is not displayed from the `$_SERVER`, instead it is displaying `REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE`

the store code for the second store is : comm

[image]

[image]

The server configuration is PHP-FPM + Mysql, it looks to me that Mage_Run_Code is not set. Because everything is working fine on my local, therefore, I think it is a server configuration issue.

---

Christophe has posted a perfect work around this, and it works perfectly.

I think I found the cause of this issue. it is the "suExec" in the Apache which securing the PHP that cause this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run magento under PHP-FPM environment, we replace (in index.php)

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

By

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ?
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE'] :
(isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '');
//$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ?
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] :
(isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store');/* Store or website code */
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful. One other question, inside the code that I have, I am using Mage_Run_code thoughout one of the plugin that I have wrote. Based on your comments, in this case, should I change every Mage_Run_Code to Redirect_Mage_Run_Code ?

Comment: yes you need to change the server variables accordingly but I would advise you not to use that kind of variables in a module as it should be cross environment and that you can see throught this example that server variables are not always the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Christophe. I have changed the everything based on your recommendations. Everything works perfectly. Learnt another thing. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean patch you can add to the top of your Magento2 `index.php` and `pub/index.php` files, or simply include it in `app/bootstrap.php`. This effectively fixes the issues when running Magento behind PHP-FPM.

This patch will fix any `$_SERVER` environment variables which have the *REDIRECT_* prefix.

```
// Fix Server Environment Variables when Using PHP-FPM
// Only run if we detect a known server variable
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE'])) {
    foreach ($_SERVER as $key => &$value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 9) === 'REDIRECT_') {
            $_SERVER[substr($key, 9)] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```